# How to trap keystrokes for control characters

Tags: javascript, events, keypress

I use a textarea with event onkeypress="f(event, this)"

but while it traps ordinary letters, in chrome at least control letters are escaping.  Is there any way to trap control characters, function keys and the like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to use the keydown (or keyup) events.  Keypress does not fire when a control key is pressed:
"The keypress event is fired when a key is pressed down and that key normally produces a character value" (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keypress).  However, keyup/keydown should fire for every key.

If you press another key while the control key is down then that key may trigger a keypress and you can check the ctrlkey, altkey, etc properties on the event to see if a special character was also active.